# How to not get an error if a data filed is not present in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling

I'm building an application with Angular 2. I am also using a database. 
I get an error if I type this line of code:

```
  <span class="col-sm-6">{{workorder.timeWindowAppointment.date}}</span>
```

The error is:

> "Cannot read property 'date' of null"

This is actually a correct error, because i don't have a property of *date* yet. I know for sure there will be a *date* property in the future.

I want Angular 2 not to throw an error, just display nothing on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **safe navigation operator** (`?`). It protects template from `null`/`undefined` values:

```
<span class="col-sm-6">{{workorder?.timeWindowAppointment?.date}}</span>
```

Read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator).

Comment: Thanks. The safe navigation operator worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can either pre-define this variable in your scope using;

```
$scope.workorder.timeWindowAppointment.date;
```

This allows you to have placement data beforehand, perhaps = new Date().toIsoString();

Or you can in your HTML;

```
<span class="col-sm-6">{{(workorder.timeWindowAppointment.date) || otherValue}}</span>
```

Again, this does a similar thing but doesn't define your variable just in case it might give you issues, and allows you to access a different variable if the primary doesn't exist.

Or you can;

```
<span class="col-sm-6" ng-if="workorder.timeWindowAppointment.date">{{workorder.timeWindowAppointment.date}}</span>
```

This will show the data if there is a defined value, but keeps the HTML layout.

Another alternative may be;

```
<span class="col-sm-6" ng-show="workorder.timeWindowAppointment.date">{{workorder.timeWindowAppointment.date}}</span>
```

This shows the data, but hides the HTML.

Comment: The solution you have given may solve the problem in Angular 1, but not in Angular 2. I used the safe navigation operator to solve it in Angular 2.

Comment: My bad, I didn't see the Angular 2 tag. I'll leave my answer up, just in case it might help someone.